# Turn json objects with the same name into columns

Tags: json, postgresql

I have this json column in my postgres v 10.18 database.

```
[{"name":"Dan","adresse":"+41 22 222 22 22, Dan@mail.com"},{"name":"Dagmar","adresse":"031 300 300, Yes@gmail.com"}]
```

Better readable.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Dan",
    "adresse": "+41 22 222 22 22, Dan@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Dagmar",
    "adresse": "031 300 300, Yes@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

The json list contacts and i can be 0 or more contacts inside.
I want to get max 5 contacts in columns like this.

[image]

Does anyone has a nice solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgresSql - Split aggregated, comma separated values into separate columns iniside query - with Amazon Aws & PostgreSql 9.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583383/postgressql-split-aggregated-comma-separated-values-into-separate-columns-ini)

Comment: Unrelated but maybe it's worth reviewing the table design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the `->` operators:

```
select the_column -> 0 ->> 'name' as contact_1, 
       the_column -> 0 ->> 'adresse' as contact_info_1,
       the_column -> 1 ->> 'name' as contact_2, 
       the_column -> 1 ->> 'adresse' as contact_info_2,
       the_column -> 2 ->> 'name' as contact_3, 
       the_column -> 2 ->> 'adresse' as contact_info_3
from the_table
```

`the_column -> 0`  picks the first array element, `->> 'name'` then retrieves the value of the key as text

Comment: select
    k.kontakte -> 0 ->> 'name'::text as Kontakt_1,
 k.kontakte -> 0 ->> 'adresse'::text as Kontaktdaten_1,
 k.kontakte -> 1 ->> 'name'::text as Kontakt_2,
 k.kontakte -> 1 ->> 'adresse'::text as Kontaktdaten_2,
 k.kontakte -> 2 ->> 'name'::text as Kontakt_3,
 k.kontakte -> 2 ->> 'adresse'::text as Kontaktdaten_3
 from personen k where id = 188714

Gives me following error:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying -> integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 24

Comment: `k.kontakte` type is `text`, right? As the error message hints, replace it with `k.kontakte::json` in the query above.

Comment: @user2210516: you stated that the column is a `json` column. Apparently that's not the case, so you will need to cast it. Or better changed the column to be a `jsonb` column.